# Multiple IDs with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Usually when I want to route an id to a Container I do:

```
<Route path={'/todo/:id'} render={({ match: { params } }) => <ToDoContainer id={params.id} />} />
```

But now I want to have two different ids in the URL, like so:

```
<Route path={'/todo/:id/category/:id'} render={({ match: { params } }) => <ToDoContainer id={params.id} />} />
```

How do I set the params? Following does not work:

```
<Route path={'/todo/:id/category/:cid'} render={({ match: { params } }) => <ToDoContainer id={params.id} cid={params.cid} />} />
```

(The names of the components are made up)

Comment: `Following does not work`. it should work, what is the error / problem?

Comment: Intellij Idea tells my `Unresolved variable`

Comment: Can you give a concrete example ? With the paths you access, etc...
Because what you wrote seems correct.

Comment: I rechecked it and after some debugging I found, that the issue was somewhere else and that the code is actually correct