# React Router multiple ids parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to handle multiple parameters in react router with the same name, i make an example to explain me better, i have a page in which I compare some items through the id of the item, so for example in a query string I have an array:

```
 &resourceid[]=123&resourceid[]=456...
```

so in this way I can have n-resourceid values. How can I achieve something like that in react router?
I have found this answer:

[Multiple IDs with React Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47289314/multiple-ids-with-react-router)

but it binds me with a specific number of ids and with multiple and different name for example `/compare/:id1/:id2/:id3....`
I don't know how many item can I have so I want something more elastic like the query string array example above.
Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Why not have one `resourceid` with multiple options comma separated? `&resourceids=123,456,789` and then you can use `this.props.match.params.resourceids.split(',')` to get an array of ids. Of course when you set it, you'll have to first grab the existing values and add the new value to the end.

Answer (score 1):

React-router v4 doesn't parse the query string anymore, see https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4410. You can do it yourself with the `query-string` package though. Either parse the query on mount & receive props, or do it in a wrapper component, like this:

```
import * as qs from 'query-string';

const Wrapper = (props) => {
  const parsedQueryParams = qs.parse(props.location.search, {arrayFormat: 'bracket'});
  return <YourComponent {...props} resourceid={parsedQueryParams.resourceid}/>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a customHistory will do the trick:

```
import { stringify, parse } from 'qs'
import { Router, useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'

const stringifyQuery = query => stringify(query, { arrayFormat: 'brackets', encode: false })

const history = useRouterHistory(createBrowserHistory)({ parseQueryString: parse, stringifyQuery })

<Router history={history} />
```

Check this issue for the discussion: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/939